# Draw an rectangle between html elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to draw a rectangle between 2

tag by javascript but i couldn't have any achievement. The things i´m trying to do is something like this:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kc4bs.jpg)

i tried to draw a rectangle by giving X, Y but the size changes when the page size changes:

```js
var x = 100;
var y = 111;
var width = 200;
var height = 40


var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'); //Create a canvas element
//Set canvas width/height
canvas.style.width = '100%';
canvas.style.height = '100%';
//Set canvas drawing area width/height
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
//Position canvas
canvas.style.position = 'absolute';
canvas.style.left = 0;
canvas.style.top = 0;
canvas.style.zIndex = 100000;
canvas.style.pointerEvents = 'none'; //Make sure you can click 'through' the canvas
document.body.appendChild(canvas); //Append canvas to body element
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
//Draw rectangle
context.rect(x, y, width, height);
context.fillStyle = 'yellow';
context.fill();

function getOffset(el) {
  el = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    left: el.left + window.scrollX,
    top: el.top + window.scrollY
  }
}
```

Comment: Are the boxes in html? Include those, and there might be a simpler way that doesn't involve a canvas.

Comment: The html approach would indeed work if everything is just a rectangle. Else, you could write a function that will calculate the height/width value as a percentage of the canvas width and height, which is in its turn a percentage of the window size and have a resize event listener as well to recalc everything. For complex graphical structures that have to be responsive, we switched to svg since it scales more easily. The svg code is even more complex to create but the headaches it gives are less frequent once you get it set up.

Comment: @Brian yea they are ul li elements. exactly i was thinking about a better way than canvas but couldn't find any those boxes are the Days and the rectangles show from day x to y there is a warning

Comment: @Shilly the thing is it should be like 2 layer one is the `li` elements and then it must shown on the top of them. is that possible to fix the start point of rectangle base on the starting point of element and it be fixed and not change when we resize the page?

Comment: You can do that with css yes. The z-index allows you to overlap any html elements and with position you can specify where elements should be lcoated in respect to eachother. Something like the css grid system (if you can use it) can also be very handy to automatically keep element heights consistent,